# Calling an async method from the browser

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

From my understanding **when we use await and the awaited task is not yet completed then the execution returns to caller**. It works fine in server side(calling the async method from server side method itself). But what happends when I call from UI to an async method.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
        IList<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        public async Task<IList<string>> GetMyCollectionAsync()
        {
            lstString.Add("First");
            string secString = await GetSecondString(); // I am expecting a response back to UI from here.
            lstString.Add(secString);
            lstString.Add("Third");
            return lstString;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetSecondString()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return "Second after await";
        }
}
```

I tested with the above API from browser like

> http://localhost:port/Test

, but I got response only after 5 sec in my UI.
Am I thinking it wrongly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I thinking it wrongly?

Yes. `async-await` does not change the nature of the HTTP protocol, which is of type request-response. When using `async-await` inside an ASP.NET controller, using an async method will not yield a response to the caller, it would only yield the requests thread back to the threadpool.

> But if this is true, then using async method having a single await in controller side is not useful. right? because it took the same time of synchronous call

Async shines when you need ***scalability***. It isn't about "yield this response as fast as possible", it's about being able to handle a large amount of requests without exhausting the thread-pool. Once the thread starts executing IO work, instead of being blocked, it is returned. Thus, able to serve more requests.

Async by itself does not make anything "go faster", which is a conception I see people thinking alot. If you're not going to be hitting your web service with many concurrent requests, you're most likely not going to be seeing any benefit from using it. As @Scott points out, an async method has a *slight overhead* as it generates a state machine behind the scenes.

Comment: To add on to the "go faster" point. Async/await actually make each request go a tiny bit *slower* but that ability to serve more concurrent requests outweighs the cost.

Answer (score 1):

async/await allow the thread to go off servicing other requests while there is that idle 5 seconds, but ultimately everything in GetMyCollectionAsync has to complete before a response is sent to the client.

So I'd expect your code to take 5 seconds and return all 3 strings in the response.

Comment: Thanks,  "everything in GetMyCollectionAsync has to complete before a response is sent to the client" this cleared my doubt,
But if this is true, then using async method having a single await in controller side is not useful. right? because it took the same time of synchronous call.

Comment: imo MS have bigged up async/await into more than it is. It doesn't really make anything any faster it just allows better use of threads that normally would be hanging around waiting for something to complete. That's my understanding of it anyway. I use async/await because it's now easy to use but it kind of solves a problem that I never felt was a problem anyway (at least in smaller apps). Stephen Cleary's blog is the place to dig deeper if you are interested,